# how to store information on disk frequently without introducing delays?

Tags: c#, streamwriter

I really don't want to introduce any delays in my high frequency trading software and at the same time I need to store thousands of lines of logs *every* second. 1 ms delay would be huge, I only agree to have 0.01-0.05 ms delay.

*Now*I just allocate 500 Mb in memory at start-up, store logs there and when application finish I put this log on disk.

However now I realized that I want more logs and I want them **during** application execution. So I now want to store logs during application execution (probably once per minute or once per 10 minute). How slow `StreamWriter.WriteLine` is? Would it be slower than just "adding to preallocated collection"?

Should I use `StreamWriter.WriteLine` directly (is it syncrhonous or asynchronous, is `AutoFlush` option affects perfomance?). I also can use `BlockingCollection` to add items to log and then use dedicated thread to process this blocking collection and to store logs on disk in another thread.

Comment: You could use a log library with rotation for 500mb. Had you take a look at log4net?

Comment: And what are your hardware constraints? This may require a separate (SSD) disk. Depending on a lot of other factors.

Comment: Did you know that both Windows multitakser and the Garbage collector could halt your prog for many (> 20) milliseconds?

Comment: @HenkHolterman I know but this will not happen 2000 times per second every second. I do happen to store logs 2000 times per second every second. I have SAS 15k 6G in Raid 0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Don't**

- Reinvent a wheel

**Do**

- Use a logging framework
- Properly configure loggers and levels for each logger
- Use *sync* logging for memory (it's simple and fast, but has problems with event persistence onto drive) and *async* for IO (it is difficult to get right, slow, harder to test) loggers

If you hadn't done so, check out [log4net](https://logging.apache.org/log4net) and [NLog](http://nlog-project.org/), this will be a good place to start.

Answer (score 0):

Probably you could store your logs in circular buffer and spawn a new thread of execution which will just send data from that buffer in shared memory to disk.

Answer (score 0):

Use log4net as Andre Calil suggests. It logs to SQL, disks and whatnot and is extremely customizable. It can seem a bit complicated at first, but it is worth the effort.

What you need is probably the `RollingFileAppender`. log4net is in nuget, but you should read the [documentation](http://logging.apache.org/log4net/release/config-examples.html)  at the log4net site. Start by looking at the appender config.